# Could you explain these statements?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlayeredpane, jdesktoppane

I've come across an example on the internet which uses both of these statements:

```
dp.add( bg , new Integer( 50 ) );
```

(dp being a JDesktopPane object and bg being a JLabel)

```
setLayeredPane( dp );
```

If you would like to know how they are used, then this is what I was looking at:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/329874/GUI/java/put-background-image-swing

I'm a beginner when it comes to Java and I understand the rest of the example, just not these two statements - and it bugs me that I don't know what they do! The bit that confuses me the most is "new Integer( 50 ) )" but please could you give a thorough, beginner-friendly explanation of both? I'd much appreciate it.

Thanks in advance,

Alex.

Comment: javadocs are best place to understand how a method works, what should be the input parameters and return type.

Comment: Your best bet for this is to first go to the API and tutorials associated with your components of interest. For instance, for JLayeredPanes, first check out the associated [JLayeredPane Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) and [JLayeredPane API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html). The tutorial comes complete with sample code and decent explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [documentation on `JLayeredPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html).

> Each layer is a distinct integer number. The layer attribute can be set on a `Component` by passing an `Integer` object during the add call.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> layeredPane.add(child, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> layeredPane.add(child, new Integer(10));
> ```

You can find the integer values of the default layer values [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html#DEFAULT_LAYER).

---

```
dp.add(lbl,new Integer(50));
```

The above adds the `JLabel` component `lbl` to the `JDesktopPane` (which *is* a `JLayeredPane`) with the specified layer of `50`. Components added to `dp` with layers that are *less than* 50 will be rendered **before**, while components with layers *greater than* 50 will be rendered **after** -- i.e. a simple depth order, where greater layers refer to nearer components.

```
setLayeredPane( dp );
```

This sets the `JFrame` represented by the `ImagePaneTest` object (which [probably shouldn't be a subclass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)) to use `dp` as its layered pane. You can see how Swing *top-level containers* work in the [relevant Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html).

[image]

Comment: @AlexanderPower no problem! Since you appear newer here, please don't forget to mark the answer [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which helped most in solving the problem.